# SQL WIndow Not Displaying for FIBDataset Component

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, fibplus

I am facing a strange problem, when I click to see SQL of TFIBDataset component, then the window seems to be open but not visible, coz once it is open i can't click in Delphi until I press Esc key. I tried pressing Alt + Tab key, but no use. then I right click on that component is chose SQL Generator option, but then also I couldn't see the SQL window.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

I was using a laptop, and a monitor was also connected to it. I made screen resolution setting on Windows 8 as "Show Desktop Only on 2".

When I was clicking on SQLs property TFIBDataset component, then the window was displaying on Laptop screen and not on Monitor screen.

Because of "Show Desktop Only on 2" setting, laptop screen was in switched off mode, so I couldn't able to notice this change.

Finally, I made the screen resolution settings as "Duplicate These Displays" and now able to see the SQL window on both the screes.

Happy At The End :)

With Best Regards.

Vishal